# Amcharts4 XYChart remove space between container and chart data

Tags: amcharts

I need to remove paddings/spaces between data visible on the XYChart.

I removed paddings from chart and tried to remove it from valueaxis and lineseries but nothing helped.

```
chart.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I also noticed that if I have more dates with values there is no space on the left and right. But what if there is less data, how to fix it.

https://codepen.io/lrobotka/pen/ZVdvyg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [startLocation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#startLocation_property) and [endLocation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#endLocation_property) on your `DateAxis` instance:

```
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
// Change this to 0.5
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
// Add the following
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;

// Change the padding values
chart.padding(0, 30, 0, 30);
```

Please check more about [setting where axis starts and ends here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_where_axis_starts_and_ends).

Comment: It worked for endLocation but it didn't do anything for startLocation so it has to be something else. https://codepen.io/lrobotka/pen/ZVdvyg

Comment: You will need the values as 0.5 and you also need to change `dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location` to 0.5. Then the label will overflow. You can re-arrange that by setting padding.